# exercicio em algoritmo visualg

Tags: algoritmo, visualg, portugol

O Custo ao consumidor de um carro novo é a soma do custo de fábrica com a porcentagem do distribuidor e com os impostos, ambos aplicados ao custo de fábrica. Sabe-se que as porcentagens são as mesmas que estão na tabela a seguir. Faça um programa que receba o custo de fábrica de carro e mostre o custo ao consumidor.

```
Custo de Fábrica        % do Distribuidor       % dos impostos  
Até R$ 12.000,00                5                   Isento 
Entre R$ 12.000,00              10                  15 
Acima de R$ 25.000,00           15                  20
```

Meu código:

```
algoritmo "Preço" 

custo_fab, perc_dist, val_dist, perc_imp, val_imp, preco: real 
inicio 
    escreva("Informe o Custo de fábrica: ") 
    leia(custo_fab) 
    se (custo_fab < 12000) entao
        perc_dist <- 5
        perc_imp <- 0 
    senao 
        se (custo_fab < 25000) entao 
            perc_dist <- 10 
            perc_imp <- 15 
        senao 
            perc_dist <- 15 
            perc_imp <- 20 
        fimse 
    fimse 
    val_dist <- custo_fab * perc_dist / 100 
    val_imp <- custo_fab * perc_imp / 100 
    preco <- custo_fab + val_dist + val_imp 
    escreval("Preço ao consumidor: ", preco) 
fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Sua dúvida é em qual ponto da tarefa? chegou a fazer alguma coisa? deu erro no código?

Comment: é que nao cosegui ententer olhe como eu fiz ai

Comment: Qual parte você não entendeu? foi algum calculo/formula? ele saiu errado?

Comment: saiu errado eu acho

Comment: Seu código parece funcionar bem, por que você acha que saiu errado? Qual foi a entrada e qual foi a saída?